# Font Awesome - Getting wrong icon for Foursquare

Tags: font-awesome

I'm using font-awesome in my website, and I'm getting the wrong icon for Foursquare brand.

I'm using this html:

```
<i class="fa fa-foursquare"></i>
```

And this is the css content, according to fontawesom.css:

```
.fa-foursquare:before{content:"\f180"}
```

which is correct, according to the official Font Awesome website.

Everything seems to be ok, but instead of the Foursquare logo, I'm getting this icon:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That icon appears to be http://iconsetc.com/icon/social-media_foursquare/?style=simple-black.

My guess is that you have a different font-based icon set loaded on your document which has the `\f180` character mapped as this icon instead, overriding the Font Awesome `fa-foursquare` icon.

A simple *fix* for this would be to:

1. Ensure your icon is using the `'Font Awesome'` font;
2. Remove your other icon font, or;
3. Ensure Font Awesome is loaded *after* your other icon font.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking into old doc for 3.X version

This is the icon in 4.3 version: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/foursquare/

and this for 3.2: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/3.2.1/icon/foursquare/

Remember that Foursquare is a brand icon: https://playfoursquare.s3.amazonaws.com/press/foursquare-brandguide.pdf